# Clipping large png make the ios app crash

Tags: ios, uiimage, png, jpeg, cgcontext

```
- (UIImage *)createThumbnailImage:(UIImage *)image withSize:(CGSize)size {
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClearRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height));

CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, 0.8);

[image drawInRect:imageRect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1];

UIImage *thumbnail = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return thumbnail;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
UIImage *inputImage =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"dog.jpg"];
UIImage *image = [self createThumbnailImage:inputImage withSize:CGSizeMake(640.0, 480.0)]
}
```

I got a thumbnail image(640 * 480) by code above. And some odd problem confused me.

When I sent a jpg (10000 * 10000) to the method，it worked well.

But when I sent a png with the same size, the app would crash.

I tried to find some documents about the difference between jpg and png, but it made no sense.

Does anyone have any idea about this bug?

Comment: You are crashing iOS because you allocate too much memory, reduce the size of those images before processing them, 10000x10000 is way too large.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIImage *)getNeedImageFrom:(UIImage*)image cropRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    CGImageRef subImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, rect);
    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:subImage];
    CGImageRelease(subImage);
    return croppedImage;
}
```

can you please check if this solve your problem

Comment: My description may have some deviation. I want to resize the image, not  to crop it. I am sorry for that . Any way , thank you for your answer = =